# Multi zone LED lighting setup

Tags: lighting, led

i am setting a multizone, 3 zone, system.

Zone 1: 4 led puck lights
Zone 2: 2 led puck lights
Zone 3: 1 led strip.

Each zone will be controlled by its own dimmer and a 4 zone remote control.

Can this all be configured to use a single power source, rated accordingly, or do I need to put each zone on its own power supply?. These zones are physically very close so I think 3 different power supplies will be an overkill.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using low voltage or line voltage dimmers for each zone? Low voltage dimmers would let you share a common power supply, line voltage would require separate ones.

Comment: These are low voltage lights. My issue is the type of connectors i need. I currently have a single zone setup with power supply connected to a single color led dimmer, which in turn is connected to a string of 4 low voltage led lights. How do I expand this to 3 zones with the same power supply. ? I have enough juice in the power supply to run 3 zones and that's not an issue.

Comment: You'll need to connect the three dimmers in parallel, e.g. if there is a red/black wire pair from the power supply to the existing dimmer then you need to cut the wires and splice them so that the red from the power supply connects to three red wires to the dimmers and similarly for the black wire. The output of each dimmer goes to one string of lights: 4 pucks, 2 pucks and the strip.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty straightforward.  You may have to graduate past connectors and actually splice some wires.